# Ejabberd user auth failed with mysql

Tags: mysql, ejabberd, ejabberd-api, xmpphp

I have installed ejabberd in my local system with mysql using below reference link. i am using php for server side use.

https://medium.com/modern-sysadmin/how-to-install-ejabberd-18-01-xmpp-server-with-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04-f0facededf2e

Everything is working fine.

i am using This PHP script https://github.com/cweiske/xmpphp/

But problem is when i add user from ejabberd web admin it works perfect to send messages. but when i add user directly in the mysql users table, both user save in users table same format same way, but when i send message using directly added user name its not working.

Getting below errors in terminal

```
09:49:48.239 [error] Supervisor ejabberd_c2s_sup had child undefined started with {ejabberd_c2s,start_link,undefined} at <0.2500.0> exit with reason no function clause matching base64:decode_binary(<<>>, <<"×mø">>, 57, 58) line 368 in context child_terminated

15:22:43.281 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.5360.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no function clause matching base64:decode_binary(<<>>, <<"×mø">>, 57, 58) line 368 in p1_server:terminate/7 line 878
```

Help me how ejabberd works with mysql users? Ejabberd save users data any other place ?

Comment: What ejabberd version, and what erlang version do you have installed? Also, did you install any other custom module?

Comment: I installed from source code in ubuntu https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/
Ejabberd version is 19.09.1.
Erland version is 10.2.4

Answer (score 0):

> but when i add user directly in the mysql users table

I have two ideas so you can investigate your problem:

- What if you create an account with plain ascii characters, for example "user123", instead of "×mø", does it work or fail?
- What if you register the account using "ejabberctl register" command line, instead of inserting elements directly in the database, does it work or fail?

I suspect the problem is in the username or password encoding when inserted in the database.